# I use Springboot. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa depends on log4j. Is it vulnerable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, log4j

Thank you.

I use Springboot and gradle.
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa depends on log4j.
Is it vulnerable?

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.2')
}
```

I haven't changed the log output settings in application.properties.

If it's not vulnerable, I want that source.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot does not have a dependency on the potentially vulnerable `log4j-core`. Only on the log4j artifacts `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-api` which are not affected by the recent CVEs:

https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot

Furthermore, Spring Boot 2.6.2 pulls in the latest releases of both logback (1.2.9) and log4j (2.17.0), which contain fixes for the recently published CVEs:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.6.2